# How to Get Value Korea Character from Properties using Java

Tags: java, localization

I have a properties file (test_ko.properties), which looks like this:

```
hello=여보세요
```

To get the content of the file above I use the Resource Bundle, as follows:

```
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test", new Locale("ko"));
String hello = bundle.getString("hello");
System.out.println("#Hello : " + hello );
```

When I run it I get the following result :

```
#Hello : ????
```

How can I get the result to look like it should:

```
#Hello : 여보세요
```

Comment: Are you printing this message on your IDE console or on your CMD.

Answer (score 0):

The above is not a legal properties file as text is limited to the ISO 8859-1 character set. Other characters must be escaped:

```
hello=\uC5EC\uBCF4\uC138\uC694
```

See:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("hello", "여보세요");
props.store(System.out, "");
```

This [may change in JDK 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/226).